# Choose download resolution in m3u8 list with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

I'm trying to download video from a m3u8 playlist using ffmpeg but I do not know how to choose the resolution to download. Currently the command is downloading the highest version

the command I am using is:

```
/home/user/bin/ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" -i "https://sitevideo.com/list.m3u8" -c copy "/home/file/video.ts"
```

My list is this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=400000,NAME="low"
size1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,NAME="med"
size2.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1900000,NAME="best"
size3.m3u8
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to use the `-map` option.

```
ffmpeg ... -i "https://sitevideo.com/list.m3u8" -map p:1 -c copy "/home/file/video.ts"
```

`p:1` refers to the 2nd program (variant playlist, in this case)..

Comment: hi here is my command can you please tell me how can I chose resolution to download in android String cmd="-i " + url +
                " -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc " +
                "-vcodec copy "+
                dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/test.mp4";

Comment: @Gyan In the map option, is there a way I can specify the index such that it would chose always choose the 2nd last variant? For example suppose the playlist may have arbitrary number of variants (ex: 5 or 8) but I don't really know how many variants it has. However, I always want to map to the 2nd last variant.

Comment: Referring to my above question the reason I want to use the 2nd lasat variant is because each variant is increasing bitrate quality for the media but I always want to choose the 2nd best available instead of the best.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't put the map command it will take the **best** quality by default.

Comment: I am experiencing some situations where I believe this is not the case.  Is there any documentation for this?  Interested to know exactly what is "best".

Comment: best means that the speed changes depending on your network badwidth (probably when the player is too much behind and starts losing frames)

Comment: @Zibri I think it selects the one with the highest resolution. See the stream selection section in the manual:

       It will select that stream based upon the following criteria:

       ·   for video, it is the stream with the highest resolution

Comment: @YağmurOymak  nope. It starts with one (sometime even the lower one) then adapts to the best for the actual bandwidth.

Comment: Zibri, not in ffmpeg. It's as @YagmurOymak says.

Comment: See [Automatic stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Automatic-stream-selection)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative variation of `-map` option:

```
ffmpeg -i <URL> -map m:variant_bitrate:800000 ...
```

That version selects the entry with `BANDWIDTH=800000` from the `list.m3u8` file.
That's also visible at the beginning of ffmpeg output, e.g.:

```
Input #0, hls, from 'http...m3u8':
  ...
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 800000
```

[Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Automatic-stream-selection)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that ffmpeg algorithm does not always select the video with best video *and audio* quality

For example, consider following HLS playlist (based on a real-world example I encountered):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4

#EXT-X-MEDIA:URI="audio_64.m3u8",TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="6",NAME="audio 0",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA:URI="audio_128.m3u8",TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="7",NAME="audio 0",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=0,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,BANDWIDTH=2966645,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2586708,RESOLUTION=1080x1920,FRAME-RATE=30,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="6"
video_1080.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=0,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE,BANDWIDTH=3030821,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2650778,RESOLUTION=1080x1920,FRAME-RATE=30,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="7"
video_1080.m3u8
```

By the bitrates you can see that the both variants have the same quality, but different sizes, as indicated by `BANDWIDTH`. Each video has `AUDIO=<id>`
that references audio with corresponding `GROUP-ID=<id>`

Judging by value of `BANDWIDTH`, video with `AUDIO="7"` has better audio quality. I have also verified that manually

ffmpeg seems to look only at `RESOLUTION`. Since both videos have same resolution, it picks the first video, as noted in [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Automatic-stream-selection):

> It will select that stream based upon the following criteria:
>
> - **for video, it is the stream with the highest resolution**,
> - for audio, it is the stream with the most channels,
> - ...
>
> **In the case where several streams of the same type rate equally, the stream with the lowest index is chosen**.

## Fix

To fix that you can manually select the best streams, and then instruct ffmpeg to use them when downloading

### Finding best streams

Use

```
ffprobe -i <path-to.m3u8> -print_format json -show_streams
```

to show information about programs and streams in the playlist files, and select the best streams (JSON is used as example, see `-print_format` option [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html))

Continuing with JSON as example, to find the best audio stream, check the
streams with `codec_type: "audio"` and compare them by `bit_rate`

For best video, check streams with `codec_type: "video"` and compare them by `tags.variant_bitrate`

### Telling ffmpeg to use those streams

Once you've found the best stream, remember `program_id` where this stream is located, and also index of the stream in the `streams` array

Next, pass `-map` option for each stream you want to download:

```
ffmpeg -i <path-to.m3u8> -map 0:p:<program-id>:<stream-index> ...
```

For explanation of the value format, see [stream specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Stream-specifiers-1)